# CVXR: addressing non-diagonal elements of a matrix of variables

Tags: cvx, cvxr

Suppose that in `CVXR` I have a definition `A <- Variable(3,3)`
and would like to maximize the function "sum of the square roots of the non-diagonal elements". However, if I write something like
`sum(sqrt(A))-sum(sqrt(diag(A)))`, the first function being concave, but the second one too, this does not comply with the `DCP Ruleset` and therefore rejected by the `CVX` engine. However, it is clear that the function is concave -- we have simply removed some of the elements in the sum,
there being no ways of saying "consider non-diagonal elements, please".
What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the second term (`term2` below) as a sum of the actual diagonals? For example,

```
e <- function(i, n = 3) {
  res <- numeric(n)
  res[i] <- 1
  res
}
diag_elem <- function(A, i) quad_form(e(i), A)
diags <- lapply(seq_len(3), diag_elem, A = A)
term2 <- sum(sqrt(do.call(vstack, diags)))
```

Comment: Correction to last statement: `term2 <- sum_entries(sqrt(do.call(vstack, diags)))`